# Buttons with ButtonBarButtonStyle do not highlight on touch

Tags: android, android-layout, android-styles

There are plenty of explanation about how to get buttons to display like standard dialogue buttons - which I follow.  I have this in my xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:divider="?android:attr/dividerVertical"
    style="?android:attr/buttonBarStyle"
    android:showDividers="middle"
    android:measureWithLargestChild="true">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_cancel"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
        android:background="@drawable/dialog_button"
        android:text="@string/button_cancel" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_ok"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
        android:background="@drawable/dialog_button"
        android:text="@string/button_ok" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This works perfectly well and produces the visual design I need. However when I touch the buttons, they don't highlight.  This is rather annoying, as everything else is exactly as it should be.  It seems that the `buttonBarButtonStyle` doesn't include the state drawables for different states of the button.  Is there an easy way to get the highlight back?

Of course, I can just define my own state drawable defining different colours, but I want to use theme colours instead.

Comment: have you tried setting             `android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"` for you `Buttons`?

Comment: @Droidman Ah! That was it, thanks!  Post it as an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to apply the background:

`android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"`

to achieve the default "button bar" style and behavior.